# Ajax error: Invalid XML when some 'strange' Unicode characters land in partial response. Is it possible to activate non-ASCII character escaping?

Tags: java, ajax, jsf, unicode, primefaces

I've suddenly got the ajax error: "Invalid XML" when doing search in PrimeFaces table. After inspection, it's a problem with parsing partial response on IE. The partial response contains the link, in which title there is a special character " ":

```
<a href="/some/link" title="Some text with strange arrow"/>
```

That "arrow" that you see only when editing the source of that question, is ASCII 26 (SUB).

I don't know how that character got into the database, but it shouldn't break the application. I'd expect the framework to somehow handle such characters (escape them or filter them out).

Is it possible to activate the escaping of non-ASCII characters in PrimeFaces/JSF partial response, or activate some filtering of potential problematic Unicode characters?

Comment: In my opinion, that's not something the framework should take care about. That's about your DB and browser encoding types. Have a look at [this](http://balusc.blogspot.com.es/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html), you might find it handy.

Comment: Since I have no control over the data in the database, and the way the framework generates the XML, I'd expect that framework enables at least some way of handling such issues. Unicode escaping is quite an universal feature, so I'd expect it should be possible to activate somehow.

Comment: I don't know if you're with JSP's or facelets. If you read the link I gave you before, it says facelets use UTF-8 by default. The framework can't do much more if it sends proper UTF-8 encoded data to a DB that is encoded in a different way, there will be problems.

Comment: I'm not sure if escaping would help anyway, but filtering invalid UTF-8 characters would fix it. So the framework can do much about it. Since it is (well?) known that (many) browsers won't process XML responses with invalid UTF-8 characters, the framework should support it, I'd expect.

Answer (score -1):

You can surround the offending section with CDATA Tags within the ajax call
so the data would be something like

```
<image_path><![CDATA[' . $imageurl['i'] . ']]></image_path>
```

Comment: Would that surrounding solve problem with invalid Unicode characters? It's the browser's parser that complaint in the first line. Is that option present in all JSF implementations or it's implementation-specific and how to activate that?

Comment: Your opening comment suggested that it is an ajax error when you are passing a url through. If you surround the ajax processed url with CDATA it should pass it through with no error. If the error is something not wanted then you can process it on the back end processor. The CDATA is an accepted solution for strange characters via ajax / json / javascript processing.